# Is there a function of comparing one list to many in python?

Tags: python, list

Let's say I have the following list:

```
a = ['a' , 'b' , 'c']
```

And I need to check if the elements of the above list, are contained in the lists below:

```
list2 = ['a' , 'b']

list3 = ['a' , 'c']

list4 = ['b' , 'c']

list5 = ['d' , 'f']
```

I need to compare the elements of one list to the elements of many lists at the same time, and the final output to be only the lists that contain these elements.

In the example, the final output would look something like:

```
list2, 

list3, 

list4
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Take a look at [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) and in particular `issubset()`.

Comment: Would be a lot simpler/nicer if you didn't have those lists in separate variables...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change them into sets and then use `issubset()`.

```py
def is_subset(sublst, lst):
    return set(sublst).issubset(lst)


a = ['a' , 'b' , 'c']

list2 = ['a' , 'b']
list3 = ['a' , 'c']
list4 = ['b' , 'c']
list5 = ['d' , 'f']

subsets = [l for l in [list2, list3, list4, list5] if is_subset(l, a)]
# subsets == [['a', 'b'], ['a', 'c'], ['b', 'c']]
```

Comment: No need to convert `lst` to set. `set.issubset` accepts any iterable.

Comment: You can use the function to build any solution you need: `if is_subset(list2, a): return 'list2'` for example.